# Transform a flat file to XML

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory, flat-file

I'm looking for options to consume flat files, transform them into XML and then send them across. I plan to accomplish this using ADF. I have noticed that there are no XML connector for a sink. My only choices seem to be creating a custom ADF activity for the conversion or rely on some function app to do the conversion.
I was wondering if there are any other suggestions.
Please let share.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other compute in your architecture?  eg Azure SQL DB is quite capable of generating xml.  Otherwise you’re looking at something like Notebooks or Mapping Data Flows.

Comment: Some simple sample data and expected results would really help.

Comment: Let me get some sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There can be no general answer to your question because an XML document can represent the data in a flat file in countless ways...

Here's one way:

```
<flatfile>Flat file content</flatfile>
```

Here's another:

```
<flatfile><w>Flat</w><w>file</w><w>content</w></flatfile>
```

And another:

```
<asdf qwerty="Flat file content"/>
```

And so on.